# ¿Como asignar un valor a un Textbox en c# usando switch?

Tags: c#, switch, textbox

tengo 2 Textbox, uno con un texto que puede cambiar manualmente y otro Textbox que está en blanco que debe cambiar su contenido dependiendo del texto del primer Textbox

```
switch(TextBox1.Text)
{
case "601":
TextBox2.Text = "general";
break;

case "602":
TextBox2.Text = "sociedad";
break;

case "603":
TextBox2.Text = "coordinación";
break;
}
```

Dependiendo del contenido del TextBox1 es el valor que se le asignará al Textbox2

Con este código no cambia el texto del TextBox2; ¿Como se soluciona?

Comment: Y vos podes asegurar que TextBox1.Text tiene alguno de esos valores? tambien podes asegurar que luego de esas lineas, nadie mas cambia el TextBox2? lo debugueaste? Lo seguiste linea por linea?

Comment: Siempre deben ser esos 3 valores, en ese caso podría usar un degault para que no agregue nada. El Textbox2 funciona como salida de datos, el usuario no tendrá acceso a Textbox2

Comment: Te da algun error?

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar.. no cambia porque no entra en ninguno, o no cambia porque esto nunca se ejecuta?

Comment: Dices que no hay otras opciones. Aún así, prueba `default: TextBox2.Text = "otros"` aunque sea para quedarnos tranquilos.

Comment: Si los valores a escribit siempre seran 601, 602 y 603, entonces probablemente debas usar un ComboBox en lugar de TextBox

Answer (score 1):

Debes agregar el codigo que tienes dentro del metodo TextChanged. Te quedaria algo similar a esto

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (textBox1.Text)
            {
                case "601":
                    textBox2.Text = "general";
                    break;

                case "602":
                    textBox2.Text = "sociedad";
                    break;

                case "603":
                    textBox2.Text = "coordinación";
                    break;
                default:
                    textBox2.Text = "Seleccione un codigo";
                    break;
            }
        }
```

PD: Verifica los nombres de las variables

Comment: Asi funciona perfectamente